# I want to insert data from first SQL table into second one also with an extra column not present in the second one

Tags: mysql, sql

So currently I am using this query

```
INSERT INTO tb_first_wallet_transactions 
(
    vendor_id, 
    amount, 
    transaction_type, 
    status, 
    checksumhash
)
SELECT 
    vendor_id, 
    amount, 
    transaction_type, 
    status, 
    checksumhash 
FROM 
    tb_second_wallet_transactions 
WHERE id = 1
```

There is also a column name `type` in `tb_first_wallet_transaction` that can be **0** or **1**, that I also needs to add, but the problem is that there is no such column in the second table.

One solution is that I run a query which changes does type == 1 after a certain time stamp (i.e of the insertion time of above query)

But I want to do all the insertion in one single query. Is that possible ??

Comment: I think you've got first and second back to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `type` in the column list and add a default value in your `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_first_wallet_transactions (vendor_id, amount, transaction_type, status, checksumhash, type)
    SELECT
        vendor_id,
        amount,
        transaction_type,
        status,
        checksumhash,
        0 -- Choose your default value
    FROM tb_second_wallet_transactions
    WHERE
        id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I didn't thought it would be that easy.